# Initialized empty array in UserProvider is not showing up in hooks for state or context

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, dropbox-api

I am creating a React Native app to view files and modify file names from dropbox.  I am using hooks and context.  In UserContext I initialized an empty array named "images."  I am trying to push the filenames from Dropbox into this array when they are authenticated and get to the home screen.  The empty array named "images" is not even showing up at all in hooks and context.

UserContext

```
import React, {useState, createContext} from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext([{}, () => {}]);

const UserProvider = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    userName: '',
    email: '',
    uid: '',
    isLoggedIn: false,
    images: [],
  });

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export {UserContext, UserProvider};
```

Home Screen

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import {UserContext} from '../context/UserContext';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append(
      'Authorization',
      'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXX',
    );
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var raw = JSON.stringify({path: `/$(user.username)`});

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow',
    };

    fetch('https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder', requestOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let tmpArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.entries.length; i++) {
          tmpArray.push(data.entries[i].name);
        }
        setUser({
          images: [...user.images, tmpArray],
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{user.username}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Does anyone know why there isn't even an empty array named images showing up?
[image: no images empty array]

This is what is being returned from the API call and I get a TypeError saying data.entries is undefined is not an object? I am bolding the two objects I have identified in the JSON as "cursor" and "entries"

{**"cursor"**: "AAHpbg4wMxtF7FNNUyW1oanIo62MWyHsdWgAG0oTDv_wpJQlTZ1CI1x0KL98E66m2rWaJVb3HEFi1KwW6dXIqEiYoXJkg7WZ2PffRktxvScYOoqd2Emodz9sQIYz2sOGvehvt3bAXbgLdZQGDtGdnmhCCxBiccIYUIFNykFCZjPq4xrOOZd3Ib31zRFzWKjSv2Ol8XELoxXkfTlSoQ9rRFk8", **"entries":** [{".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:26Z", "content_hash": "b5bd5c666d2c61594248bc025fb6e35f097596778eafec58c0941fcdb27d95e9", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALfA", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "IMG_9440.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/IMG_9440.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img_9440.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1190000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 41614}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:34Z", "content_hash": "4d7544436f557cf8829a034feeb1a607e226b4db4a5e7e8d702f9e0d7ab81850", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALgg", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img046.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img046.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img046.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd11a0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 70165}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:37Z", "content_hash": "97ac717a0344ac319c4ed40d7790d320588fbe2e018413bac983ddea8bf1db26", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALhA", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img054.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img054.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img054.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd11b0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 61860}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:40Z", "content_hash": "106916fd461c4270d981b28001e9fb18195326198eeb96c6a2b0fbc05db08eb0", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALhw", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img077.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img077.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img077.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd11c0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 55785}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:44Z", "content_hash": "8f5eaedcc9c6b833ba76d18dfd5387d0909fc2186dc183942a6192dc585fbea0", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALiQ", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img079.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img079.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img079.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd11d0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 68128}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:52Z", "content_hash": "658ebee2da4ea30164751b02cf785c84c7717383e9aa8eeb26daa4d57423d6cc", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALkA", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "Untitled-10.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/Untitled-10.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/untitled-10.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd11e0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 57502}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:05Z", "content_hash": "4467b389d485dab36b2f07910b2c88a4702c6313bb7edfd462f07f43281cf9b9", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALbA", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1958.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1958.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1958.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd11f0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 74876}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:21Z", "content_hash": "cd767e1480e1db87c842574d131f2256ae99f5423fcfec644b7a1a0e84115902", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALeA", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1986 family photo.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1986 family photo.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1986 family photo.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1200000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 73519}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:09Z", "content_hash": "517316127dba91558a5155dd1fa7f6ecc0016d4fbdebb04a06674efe5325b169", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALbw", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1974 kids halloween.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1974 kids halloween.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1974 kids halloween.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1210000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 82047}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:10Z", "content_hash": "a11064b5b64e5fb0c5b9e19eca7542d67ff0e89a85e083fbc13d6f108206bbe1", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALcA", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1977 Don helicopter.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1977 Don helicopter.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1977 don helicopter.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1220000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 78497}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:15Z", "content_hash": "fea587a81b1a34c76d3cc6069f59a6380591b766b99930453ee94fa9a062d2da", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALdA", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1983 Gay Nell Flower necklace.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1983 Gay Nell Flower necklace.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1983 gay nell flower necklace.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1230000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 103859}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:22Z", "content_hash": "dafbed004306248c3b3238681fcdb468694d5b3f8f14597a79a66bd3cd1314af", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALeQ", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1986 kids on a horse.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1986 kids on a horse.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1986 kids on a horse.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1240000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 91012}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:25Z", "content_hash": "7503df4b2e3aeb8e5388d305d2e7bf08457a6c71b95f972566ffb1282b1be635", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALew", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "IMG_5485.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/IMG_5485.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img_5485.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1250000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 56205}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:36Z", "content_hash": "08e13d1db5a5c8439b1f25bab58bef15fc7ea2ec9ce7600b50ac581ab6eb6c0e", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALgw", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img049.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img049.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img049.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1260000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 87449}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:02Z", "content_hash": "372ae95264edf6ca0a98a57b942982a72bcc165b6c5a3b2397473e82cabd2da0", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALag", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1952 Love Donald.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1952 Love Donald.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1952 love donald.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1270000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 68978}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:06Z", "content_hash": "efa2eebf7c47a7669de1a6e7c802e2f5dd8cef11f82abc29aeed03b5eb132f87", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALbQ", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1960 group photo.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1960 group photo.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1960 group photo.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1280000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 54658}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:49Z", "content_hash": "71ef0691e64e8e2e27f2effc2169eb4ec4683ac130536371c230139ab876c4ed", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALjQ", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img085.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img085.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img085.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1290000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 74486}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:38Z", "content_hash": "0d58794392979bba6524d286bc4333fbab9c05f7020d57a4b6c9064db2924757", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALhQ", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img057.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img057.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img057.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd12a0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 71882}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:47Z", "content_hash": "46a12ba282d5bcc118f2bfb50d69a93dc4c30984f533335485d5ce6d0648ab8b", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALjA", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img083.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img083.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img083.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd12b0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 61361}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:29Z", "content_hash": "7551ea66b4ba075d2577c6fc9baf6d51afef4953188a6d441e4b82db8f6eff3e", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALfg", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img037.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img037.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img037.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd12d0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 65024}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:50Z", "content_hash": "0bc733c59c767f2a32a52323adb259941cd59f3fb1b713721e35177768e49180", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALjg", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img087.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img087.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img087.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd12e0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 60538}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:13Z", "content_hash": "0acab887396b29bc88e65a362f8cd7c6a445da38ed1770246ea64970b3814828", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALcg", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1978 kids with santa.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1978 kids with santa.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1978 kids with santa.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd12f0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 71605}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:19Z", "content_hash": "be9f666a14f87cacf6a4a881a9ff186641cff59e11016d1d50f7b53b6d5abe6f", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALdw", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1986 Bowling photo 2.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1986 Bowling photo 2.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1986 bowling photo 2.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1300000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 77599}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:46Z", "content_hash": "20996a75d90163d51af2b567ecf685a85c57c70c5d403e225dd389ecb6e4f6ea", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALiw", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img082.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img082.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img082.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1310000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 86992}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:11Z", "content_hash": "aa4740735870ae206fc7d2d3cc49744ee691925b0d0ac92d9cad02a4a54dfad1", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALcQ", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1978 issa bigger goober fish.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1978 issa bigger goober fish.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1978 issa bigger goober fish.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1320000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 52196}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:33Z", "content_hash": "6d76a31bf215484070b7670e1afd451084f06af9924238df2364352b32034539", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALgQ", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img044.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img044.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img044.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1330000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 104988}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:17Z", "content_hash": "1fff761ae247682b33f40860541a8bdc74a1e05bebb8e64567437fd2d0f01b24", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALdQ", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1983 Gay Nell in a bikini.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1983 Gay Nell in a bikini.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1983 gay nell in a bikini.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1340000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 90905}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:18Z", "content_hash": "1ba137933334875d41810125754232aad4cf80ca8b207774868b621746570d40", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALdg", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1983 Gay Nell sunglasses.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1983 Gay Nell sunglasses.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1983 gay nell sunglasses.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1350000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 52394}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:24Z", "content_hash": "8736636127dc42e80f35fda4c53929c50227dc149655232e2b69c2e790aecb46", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALeg", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1990 Bowling photo.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1990 Bowling photo.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1990 bowling photo.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1360000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 63931}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:30Z", "content_hash": "b7c077b2f7519659bf69e0f339722df551165ce1d52253030bce562f9d64cf09", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALfw", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img039.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img039.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img039.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1370000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 87483}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:42Z", "content_hash": "1c8f63a10dc099644a36768132f44e32d88a07231064ca31d5635a35867d11d9", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALiA", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img078.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img078.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img078.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1380000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 69665}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:08Z", "content_hash": "e00305b58e1b596b6f771504cf3a3a7924d95a90affdb4a3a4fbf96aa990abf3", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALbg", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1962 Gay Nell.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1962 Gay Nell.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1962 gay nell.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd1390000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 53397}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:14Z", "content_hash": "34cff34e0533444b3eb421d42b6a1a06e61714deb179d46ed72e364bb606d998", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALcw", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1979 Birthday cake.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1979 Birthday cake.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1979 birthday cake.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd13a0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 65964}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:04Z", "content_hash": "712bc0d91b008f582bab0718df978137abf1596ca84b793edd956e0e6dd05c6f", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALaw", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1958 lovebirds.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1958 lovebirds.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1958 lovebirds.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd13b0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 87072}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:45Z", "content_hash": "270cab519878b26af5dc91f365cde407120392247d5818fbf157f35f6469a1ea", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALig", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img080.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img080.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img080.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd13c0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 55588}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:51Z", "content_hash": "3c616ba0675980a4e92d27b9192d8f465db31d4292c9dd0dfba075f3b39bd98c", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALjw", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "Untitled-1.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/Untitled-1.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/untitled-1.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd13d0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 58701}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:32Z", "content_hash": "609892799fc1ce438f050af20c18f97eb7beee669975a3dd5c647a53abcc8b03", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALgA", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img043.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img043.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img043.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd13e0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 81765}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:39Z", "content_hash": "9ba6ab64e2f6001cef9d7f8e3a452e8ebe2da1564fe856dec6e42ae94edc9d6d", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALhg", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "img066.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/img066.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/img066.jpg", "rev": "015bd9742bbd13f0000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-15T18:17:20Z", "size": 56767}, {".tag": "file", "client_modified": "2021-03-15T17:39:28Z", "content_hash": "0dc7efcefcf6ff2babe3b985cb19d1ebfe331b3740e75ecc76c4ea7d6a91c231", "id": "id:MLd4r5eYWjwAAAAAAAALfQ", "is_downloadable": true, "name": "1950-Joe-Horse.jpg", "path_display": "/joeault/1950-Joe-Horse.jpg", "path_lower": "/joeault/1950-joe-horse.jpg", "rev": "015bda95957f6d80000000229a28d10", "server_modified": "2021-03-16T15:52:09Z", "size": 85665}], "has_more": false}

Comment: You verified that you got a response from endpoint 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder ?

Comment: your namedImages isn't showing because you updated state why you got a response from /auth and  you deleted your props, you need to verify that you got a response from endpoint 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder ?
In order to update your state you need to merge other values like this: {...user, images: imagesUpdated}

Comment: I have confirmed I am getting a response from the server but it gives me TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.entries') I am adding the data it returned (the json) above so it is more viewable

Comment: Can you plz show me the data ?

Comment: I just posted it above and bolded the two objects.  I am trying to access the "entries" and looping through that.

Comment: It's weird, your code should work, plz do a console(data.entries), to see if data.entries is full,it can be undefined.

Comment: Will do and report back.

Comment: Ok.  I did data.entries and only the entries showed.  Then I did .length and it shows 39.  Then I used the code again and I get "error [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.entries')]"  What?!

Comment: When I do .then(data => console.log(data.entries[0])) I get that specific entry.   When I do .then(data => console.log(data.entries[0].name)) I get that specific name.  When I do .then(data => console.log(data.entries.length)) I get 39.  It makes no sense. Once I put in the if loop, it tells me undefined.

Comment: Ok.  Everything is working excpet for the context/state update.  I changes it to setUser({
          ...user,
          images: tmpArray,
        });
        console.log(user.images); and I get undefined again.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230174/discussion-between-gmacerola-and-soufiane-boutahlil).

Comment: tmpArray works.  I can see the array.  But it has to be moved into the context so the whole app can see it.... that is what is getting undefined.  I can't add the tmpArray to the empty array I initialized with.....

Answer (score 0):

The problem was spreading the stat in setUser.

This is what it was:

```
setUser({
          images: [...user.images, tmpArray],
        });
```

This is what I changed it to:

```
setUser({
          ...user,
          images: tmpArray,
        });
```

Soufiane Boutahlil was correct.